# Swift - Segue from Button inside a cell

Tags: swift, cell, segue

i have a custom cell attached to TableViewCell class, and i have a button inside that custom cell, i want whey i press the button it segues to another view controller, but the:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)
```

function is not recognised, how to fix that ?

Edit:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 19):

`-performSegueWithIdentifier:` method is declared in `UIViewController`. So you can't just call it in `UITableViewCell` subclass.

You can add an action to that button when you are creating cell in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexpath:` method. Then you can call `-performSegueWithIdentifier:` method in that action method. Here is example assuming we are in `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "someAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

And here is action method:

```
func someAction() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToView", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: This solves a problem I spent hours on. Thanks. Is this a best practice? It's easy and it works, so that's a good thing. Consideration to take into account is preparing segue to pass data to the moveToView

Comment: please show how you define your segue... Because it is not working for me ;(

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom class for your cell. In that class, create an `@IBAction` as response to the button click. In that action, perform your segue.

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier` is a function of UIViewController. You can create an `@IBOutlet` in your custom cell class and connect it to the TableViewController it belongs to. Then you are able to perform the segue with `myTableViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interface Builder:

Connect your firstViewController to the secondViewController - and create a Segue Identifier.

Then you are able to use

```
performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)
```

Comment: connect your cell (not the button) to the secondViewController

Comment: The problem is not with the connection, it's with identifying the function itself. The compiler is not accepting it.

Comment: Please post a Screenshot of your Storyboard.